# Why does Windows Filtering Platform apply ALE reauthorization for EVERY single incoming multicast UDP packet from same source?

Tags: multicast, windows-server-2019, wfp, windows-networking

[image]I am using iperf network testing tool and observe the following: if, on box A (Windows Server 2019), I have a single sender that posts to some multicast address/port, and 5 multicast receivers, joining same multicast group, on box B (also Windows Server 2019), there will be packet loss at certain packet rate, which does NOT happen in case of single receiver, so it is NOT sender or wire level loss

Exploring with xperf (stackwalk with DPC details) shows that there  is some relevant activity in ntoskrnl.exy, but in netio.sys, it points to tcpip.sys!WfpAleReauthorizeConnection , which is called from tcpip.sys!TlShimOptionalReauthorizeConnection. The part "optional" feels like it's not something that HAS TO happen. Is there a way to control it and make it to not take that option?

Looking at the WFP performance counters, I see that counter "Reason:NewInboundMCastBCastPacket" (WFP Reauthorization counter group) value is exactly equal to the number of UDP datagram processed (input stream packet rate multiplied by 5, because 5 receivers). That tells me Reauthorization is indeed applied to every single packet. There has to be a way to control this.  The issue is not limited to testing tool - we have an actual application, which is also "5 copies of multicast receivers" that is running into same exact issue.

Windows Defender Firewall is off, so, it is not something that it is doing. Switching network profile from "public" to "private".  Adding a filter to explicitly permit all UDP traffic at FWPM_LAYER_ALE_AUTH_RECV_ACCEPT_V4 layer did not change anything - I am guessing I need to somehow adjust filtering engine to not even try to apply filtering, but WFP documentation is extremely vague , and there is NO mentioning of NewInboundMCastBCastPacket as a possible cause of WFP ALE reauthorization

Tried the following:
Completely uninstalled Symantec Endpoint Protection
Tried to add FWP_ACTION_PERMIT at FWPM_LAYER_ALE_AUTH_RECV_ACCEPT_V4 layer to allow ALL inbound UDP traffic (but I think I need a way to force FWP engine to not even apply the checking)
Switched network profile from "Public" to "Private"

Comment: Needs more context, specifically the nature of the communication between the client and server. At a higher level, `FWP_CONDITION_REAUTHORIZE_REASON_NEW_INBOUND_MCAST_BCAST_PACKET` is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fwp/filtering-condition-flags-) as `Indicates that new inbound multicast or broadcast packets are being re-authorized at ALE_RECV_ACCEPT callouts.`. Multicast/broadcast ALE flows are [handled differently](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fwp/ale-multicast-broadcast-traffic) than unicast ALE flows.

Comment: `All inbound multicast and broadcast traffic at the Application Layer Enforcement (ALE) layers is mapped to one global ALE flow. Response traffic for inbound multicast and broadcast packets is classified at the FWPM_LAYER_ALE_AUTH_CONNECT_V{4|6} layer and separate ALE flows are created for each response.` My reading of this is that all inbound multicast/broadcast traffic is going to result in reauthorization since there's only one global ALE flow.

Comment: Why specifically do you suspect packet loss is due to this reauthorization? Try adding some discard callouts at various layers and see what the discard reason is.

Comment: @Luke - nature of communication is pretty trivial. There is a single data source that posts the data to multicast group, single UDP port. On a physical box, there could be 1 or more receivers that join the same multicast group and listen on that port. In the actual application, the packet rate varies and packet size varies between 300 and 1100  bytes. iperf test is just doing stable packet rate with fixed packet size.

Comment: @Luke - the documentation is very confusing to me. This specific one - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fwp/ale-multicast-broadcast-traffic - puzzles me a lot. It says "By default, the authorization of an outbound multicast or broadcast ALE packet will permit inbound traffic, whether unicast, multicast, or broadcast, from any remote address for up to 4 seconds". What scenario does that even apply to? Does "permit inbound traffic" in this context mean that re-authorization won't need to be applied? Or that re-authorization will permit it?

Comment: @luke - what's confusing to me about re-authorization is that if I have an application that joined multicast, and listening on UDP port, why does every single packet need reauthorization? The documentation seems to imply that reauthorization is a "bad" or at least "expensive" this. The partial list of causes for re-authorization mentioned here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fwp/ale-re-authorization - seems to indicate that it is something not taken lightly  and is done when something significant changes.

Comment: @luke I suspect that re-authorization at least partially responsible. xperf shows that re-authorization activity is at least a part of hot path when looking at the DPC usage. The packet loss starts to happens when packet rate is high enough for DPC% utilization of the single core to reach and stay at 100%. It's bad enough that it all gets bottlenecked on a single core(something I need to research too), it is wasting significant effort on a completely useless (in this context) reauthorization. Why is there "Optional" in TlShimOptionalReauthorizeConnection ? or it is not optional for mcast?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257253/discussion-between-alexander-safronov-and-luke).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there is a way to [exempt multicast traffic](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/datagram-loss-when-you-run-a-multicast-receiver-application-in-windows-8-and-in-windows-server-2012-0f7a55e3-5073-4cdd-d7a6-8a40e7fb92a5) from inspection by UDP port:

> You can create a `REG_MULTI_SZ` type registry key named `UdpExemptPortRange` to configure the port ranges that are exempted from the base filtering engine. To do this, create the registry key in the following path:
>
> `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\Parameters`
>
> For example, you can configure the following value in the registry key:
>
> - `3400`
> - `1000-1030`
> - `2000-2050`
>
> The smallest port number to use is `1` and the highest is `65535`.
>
> Notes
>
> - Each exempted port range should be in a new line.
> - You must restart the computer after you changed the registry key.

Comment: Thanks! Rolling out the change. Initial test looks good